# Is it possible to make a folder based on user input?

Tags: php

Is it possible to make directory based on user input, i want to store their cookies and also create directory for them to access on the site.
User input are the below

```
 $cid = $_POST['cid'];
 $gid = $_POST['gid'];
```

Original of the code :

```
 mkdir('/home/user/public_html/ref/', 0777 );
```

I want the code to exist like this :

```
 mkdir('/home/user/public_html/ref/',$cid."_".$gid, 0777 );
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Did you experience any problems? If so which ones?

Comment: @Oswald, first one gives an error of directory already exist.

2nd one just gives me error.

i want to create a folder for the input based by user .

Comment: This really helps , is it possible to do an if else statement lets say the directory is already created , we could redirect them to google or something?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `,` you should concat directory path with `.`

Just try with:

```
mkdir('/home/user/public_html/ref/' . $cid . "_" . $gid, 0777);
```

Comment: This really helps , is it possible to do an if else statement lets say the directory is already created , we could redirect them to google or something?

Comment: `mkdir` returns `true/false` which says if it has created directory or not.

Comment: but it will affect the layout of the page , that's why im fearing the most.

Comment: What do you mean "affect the layout" ?

Comment: Header will mentioned error - directory already been created in the following (home/user/public_html).

Answer (score 0):

Try it:
    mkdir('/home/user/public_html/ref/' . $cid . "_" . $gid, 0777 );

Comment: This really helps , is it possible to do an if else statement lets say the directory is already created , we could redirect them to google or something?

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said before me use:

```
mkdir('/home/user/public_html/ref/' . $cid . "_" . $gid, 0777, true);
```

Notice the "true" 3rd variable.
This will allow mkdir() to create recursively any missing directories.